# How to programmatically press "Send" button, after opening WhatsApp from another app via FlutterOpenWhatsapp

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

The code below works perfectly :

```
FlutterOpenWhatsapp.sendSingleMessage(
      person.phoneNumber,
      "Hello Mars!");
},
```

It opens Whatsapp from this app, pastes the message to text field, but user needs to press "Send" button to complete the task.

Is there a way to press "send" button on Whatsapp programmatically with FlutterOpenWhatsapp or another way...

Thanks in advance.
Oz

Comment: There is no way to programmatically push the buttons in another application.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought WhatsApp api or some other tool might have the option...